# Rename a field in each object of a list

Tags: javascript

I have a list of object, each object has a field `name`:

```
let data = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}, {name: 'ipsum'}];
```

I would like to rename the `name` field to `title`. I tried following:

```
data.map(el => {el.title = el.name});

  console.log(`${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
```

However, the result is that each object has an additional field `title` instead of renaming `name` field to `title`. How can I rename the `name` field to `title` for each object in a list?

Comment: You can add a `delete el.name` after adding the new key. If you don't want to mutate the original array, `let newData = data.map(({ name: title }) => ({ title }))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create new array using `Array#map` with key of `title`

```js
let data = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}, {name: 'ipsum'}];

let res = data.map(el => ({title:el.name}));

console.log(res)
```